# How can I Select Only the latest row in a join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to complicated SQL Query so please excuse me if this problem might be simple to solve.
I have a Table with VocabCards the important Column is only the ID. Then I have a VocabCardEvent Table which saves the Events that happen to this VocabCard. The Event I have to get at this Use Case is the change of the Difficulty. The important columns are the ID(varchar), the CreatedDate(DateTime), and the Type(int) which saves the change of difficulty. The ID has 16 characters: 8 from the flashcard and 8 unique ones.

Now to my Question:
I need to get all VocabCards and the corresponding **newest** VocabCardEvent. How can I achieve this?

What I've done so far:

- Subquery (Problem: I can't pass the current Flashcard Id to the Subquery so I always get the first VocabCardEvent)
- Join with Top(1) and Order by CreatedDate (Problem: I only get one VocabCard)
- Join with Subquery (Problem: I get all VocabCardEvents so I have one VocabCard multiple times)

I hope this explanation is all right. Thanks for trying to help in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, `APPLY` is a very good approach:

```
select vc.*, vce.*
from VocabCards vc outer apply
     (select top (1) vce.*
      from VocabCardEvents vce
      where vce.vocabcardid = vc.id
      order by vce.createddate desc
     ) vce;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(select vc.*, vce.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by vc.id order by vce.createddate desc) as rn
from VocabCards vc 
Join VocabCardEvents vce
  On vce.vocabcardid = vc.id) t
Where rn = 1
```